# Delete Rows in a group Except one of them SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, common-table-expression

I have this situation:

[image]

I need delete one of the distinct row, I mean, only need one of "1, 1, 1," and only need one of  "2, 2, 2" in a CTE on SQL, but how you can see i cannot use a distinct.

Comment: **`SELECT DISTINCT ...`**

Comment: Make a copy table, do insert into copy select distinct from originaltable.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @Quassnoi nice of you to decide this is sql-server, would you mind explaining?

Comment: @sagi: well I know what a screenshot of SSMS result pane looks like

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH    t AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3) ORDER BY (id) rn
        FROM    mytable
        )
DELETE
FROM    t
WHERE   rn > 1
```

Comment: @SebastianPelaez: the answer still works. If would help immensely if we saw your actual table layout (unless you really named all your columns "(No column name)")

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest something simple:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_table AS
SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2,col3 FROM YourTable;

DELETE FROM YourTable;

INSERT INTO YourTable
SELECT * FROM tmp_table;

DROP TABLE tmp_table;
```

This will basically recreate your table with distinct values using a temp table.

**Note:** There is more efficient ways to do this, but you didn't specify your DBMS, and it may change from one to another. This solution is for ANSI SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte_del as
(
select *,row_number() over (partition by col1,col2,col3 order by  col1,col2,col3) as rownum from yourtable 
) 
delete from cte_del where rownum > 1
```

Good if you read more about Row_Number(), Rank(), DenseRank()